# Android - Alarm doesn`t fire sometimes after long period

Tags: android

I have a big problem with my app for several days now. I appologize if my english is not so native in advance. I implemented an AlarmManager to give the user of my app the option to start a certain service at any time of the current or the next day. So e.g. the user might choose to set the time for my service to tomorrow at 08:00 a.m. and then starts the service.

The alarm manager should now wait the calculated time from now till the chosen time (i calculated the time also manually and it is correct!) and then start the service. My problem now is that sometimes the alarmmanager is starting my service and somtimes not. It seems that if it has to wait for lets say more than 4 hours it is not working any more and my service is not called. I have set all neccessary permission otherwise it would not work at all. You can have a look at the code of the alarmmanager below:

```
someIntent = new Intent();
someIntent.setAction("START_SERVICE");
AlarmManager alarams ;

alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, someIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarams = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarams.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+delay, alarmIntent);
```

The broadcast receiver is implemented like this (and it is registered!):

```
alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
                startService(myIntent);
            }
        };
```

As I told you, if it is not working it stops before starting the service.

EDIT:
I have an idea. I read something in this thread: [Android long running service with alarm manager and inner broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138597/android-long-running-service-with-alarm-manager-and-inner-broadcast-receiver)

It might be, that my constructor for the intent "someIntent" only works for BroadcastReceivers declared in the manifest file. So in my case I should maybe use `someIntent = new Intent("START_SERVICE")` instead of `someIntent = new Intent(); someIntent.setAction("START_SERVICE")`. This effect is called tunneling - i will figure it out, if it works i will post my experience here. Thanks for the well explained answer on the mentioned thread! If you have any other ideas or the same experiences like me please let me know!
eMu

Answer (score 0):

If the device is shutdown and start up then you will not get the alarm maanger broadcast receiver.
Implement OnBootReceiver which will receive the OnBoot completed and there you can start your pending alarms that were not fired.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. The device is not shutting down in between. It is just going into sleep mode, but this should not affect the alarm manager because of the RTC_WAKEUP.

Comment: yes, in that case RTC_WAKEUP should have delivered the intent.

Comment: So the AlarmManager still does not work for me after testing more and more and I don't understand why. I read smth. about the WAKE_LOCK and that my Service might not be called anymore before the phone goes into sleep mode after the broadcast receiver is being called. Can this be the reason? I really hope you can help me!!!!

Best Regards eMu

Comment: Yes, if you have not implemented WAKE_LOCK then you won't get the intent. Best approach for you is to go through or use cwac-wakeful service in your app. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you think it would be enough if i implement in my BroadcastReceiver something like:               PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "MY_WAKE_LOCK");
wl.acquire();
startService(myIntent);
wl.release();                                                        what i mean is, is it enough if i just hold the WAKE_LOCK before i start my service, then it gets started and then i can release it again?

Comment: I think it should be good to go. Did you try the alarm with taking wake lock?

Comment: just implemented it and now iam running it on my phone, lets see. Iput the alarm to 7.a.m. tomorrow to start my Service. But somehow i have a bad feeling that it will not work :( By the way, do you know what does it mean when I see in the logcat "Process com.tecent.mm has died" -> from this results a WIN DEATH in my app. With best regards

Comment: I think after i read some more about the alarm manager and the power manager i have to aqquire the power manager in the broadcast receiver and release it then after i started my service in the service. I will give this an approach and tell you about my experience.

Comment: you can use the cwac wakeful service in your app. github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: @user1386502 use logcat app from the play market and start recording logging. Check if you are actually getting the control and receiving intent in your alarm receiver after a gap of say overnight.