# Why service is killing after one or two days?

Tags: android

i just used a Alarm Manager to initiate a broadcast receiver and that broadcast receiver calling to a service. This whole process is called again and again after a fixed interval of time as i have already set in my alarm service. But still i am facing a problem that my service is killing after one or two days in some android device. Following is my code.

This is where i am calling broadcast receiver from.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(NotificationFirstActivity.this,
                MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                NotificationFirstActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

And this is my broadcast receiver like as follows.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }

    }

}
```

Following is my manifest part like as.

```
<service android:name="MyAlarmService"
                 android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name="MyReceiver"/>


         <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="com.phoenixmanage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
         <service android:name="com.phoenixmanage.GCMIntentService" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have used in one of my application, working perfectly. i have used this to post the data on server in every 15 min.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

        public static final String ACTION_PING = "com.example.ACTION_PING";
        public static final String ACTION_CONNECT = "com.example.ACTION_CONNECT";
        public static final String ACTION_SHUT_DOWN ="com.example.ACTION_SHUT_DOWN";

        private final static String TAG = "BackgroundService";
        static Context context;
        private static volatile PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic = null;

        long INTERVAL =AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;

    public static Intent startIntent(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
            i.setAction(ACTION_CONNECT);
            return i;
    }

        public static Intent pingIntent(Context context) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
            i.setAction(ACTION_PING);
            return i;
        }

        public static Intent closeIntent(Context context) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
            i.setAction(ACTION_SHUT_DOWN);
            return i;
        }

        synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
            if (lockStatic == null) {
                PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

                lockStatic = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
                lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
            }

            return (lockStatic);
        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    context = this;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            Log.i(TAG, "onStart");

        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock lock = getLock(this.getApplicationContext());

            if (!lock.isHeld()) {
                lock.acquire();
            }

            if (intent != null) {
                if (ACTION_SHUT_DOWN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    stopSelf();
                    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
                }
            }

            if (intent == null || (intent.getAction() != null && !intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SHUT_DOWN))) {
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                BackgroundService.pingIntent(this),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
                if (operation == null) {
                PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, BackgroundService.pingIntent(this), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pm.isScreenOn() ? SCREEN_ON_INTERVAL : SCREEN_OFF_INTERVAL, operation);
                }
            }

            //fetch parsms and make your web service call here

            return START_STICKY;
        }
```

use this to start the service

```
startService(BackgroundService.startIntent(context));
```

use this to terminate the service

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                 PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                 BackgroundService.pingIntent(context),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
                 if (operation != null) {
                 am.cancel(operation);
                 operation.cancel();
                }
                context.startService(BackgroundService.closeIntent(context));
```

**NOTE:** if your device is reboot, your alarm is cancelled, so if you want recreate it you should create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for the action android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and allow you to call the above code for setting the repeating alarm.

Answer (score 0):

there may chances of following things .
1) If the device is shutdown and start up then you will not get the alarm maanger broadcast receiver. Implement **OnBootReceiver** which will receive the **OnBoot completed** and there you can start your pending alarms that were not fired.
ref : [Android - Alarm doesn`t fire sometimes after long period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531451/android-alarm-doesnt-fire-sometimes-after-long-period)

2) http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/scheduling-task-using-alarm-manager.html

Comment: check on reboot you will get log of receiver or not

Comment: Even after rebooting my service is working, the main problem is that after two or three days service automatically destroys.

Comment: each device facing issue !!

Comment: No as i am having application in my htc desire , it's working fine but in samsung there is problem.

Comment: test it again on another model. then it hardware issue !!  post on hardware section

Comment: NO i don't think so it's a programming problem.